# emerging caption in the fourth edge of a larger square containing figures on other three edges

Tags: floats

How can I insert 3 figures in a one column format article as below:

[image]

[an answer is here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222117/multiple-panel-figure-with-caption-in-one-of-the-panels) but the result of this answer will be

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222117/multiple-panel-figure-with-caption-in-one-of-the-panels?rq=1.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work!! I will see all figures in one column!

Comment: Delete this question then ask another using the code you used to generate the picture.

Comment: @John Kormylo, thank you so much for your suggested Address. the new address http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/subcaption-package-compatibility-issue is the adsress solved new problem. we have to add \captionsetup{compatibility=false}