# Positioning of caption in left figure space

Tags: floats, captions

I am quite new into the LateX world but I gave it a chance since I am writing my thesis. I learnt a lot and so far I resolved all my questions thanks to the forum and previous users. However, I do not manage with the following problem even tho I know there are several topics about it. I read them all but the do not exactly help with what I need.

Probably is a very simple issue but for me it is quite the opposite!

Anyway, this img pictures what I am trying to do:

[image]

I played with minipages and several other ways but I dont manage. Can you help me?

I tried this [Multiple panel figure, with caption in one of the panels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222117/multiple-panel-figure-with-caption-in-one-of-the-panels), but since I have a big figure (a) instead of two, I got lost modifying the code.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Figure A and B should be part of figure 4? Do you like only one caption for both?

Comment: Also, if possible please post your MWE ...

Comment: Hi both and thanks for answering! A and B belong to Figure 4, yes. They do not carry a subcaption. My code is basically the one i nthe answer of the linked topic. It is basically useless since I just try to modify things inside that one, but I am not achieving that result.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?s=4|26.1122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE shows two different examples on how to achieve the desired result. The first uses `minipage`s in order to position the small image and the caption. The second shows how to adapt the answer that you refered to to your images. However, you don't really need `subfigures` if the individual images do not get additionaly individual subcaptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{example-image}

\medskip

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\caption{some long caption text that spans several lines on the document}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
%\centering
\vspace{0pt}% set the real top as the top
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
\caption{Some general caption of all the figures.}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried the first option you suggested, since it is true that I don't need subfigures if I don't need subcaptions.

That way, the figures are placed as in my draft, but the caption lies below the second one, instead of being placed in the "free space" on the right. Why is that?

Comment: @ThesisWriter: Does this happen with the above MWE or if you insert the code in your original document? Typically, the minipage that contains the caption is pushed below the second image if the combined widths of the caption's minipage and the second image's minipage is much wider than the textwidth. Please also do not insert blank lines above or below `\hfill` as this will lead to undesired placements. Lastly, you might need to be careful if the caption is longer than the height of the second image. In that case, the distance between first and second image is increased.